# About unions of tables with aggregate functions

Tags: mysql, mariadb

I have two tables (individuales and grupales). I want to create a view where I can calculate the totals of the three columns.  (condones_entregados, lubricantes_entregados y materiales_educativos_entregados). These columns are in both tables respectivelly.
I had to create a view for each table where I calculate the SUM of these columns to get the total. And then, I had to create a new view to perform the join between them. 
It is long but I have been trying many different ways and have never succeeded.

Tabla de Grupal

```
   SELECT 
        SUM(`condones_entregados`) AS `total_C`,
        SUM(`lubricantes_entregados`) AS `total_L`,
        SUM(`materiales_educativos_entregados`) AS `total_M`,
        `id_persona_receptora`
    FROM
        `promotor_realiza_actividad_grupal_con_personas_receptoras`
    GROUP BY `id_persona_receptora`
```

Tabla de Individual

```
    SELECT 
        SUM(`condones_entregados`) AS `total_C`,
        SUM(`lubricantes_entregados`) AS `total_L`,
        SUM(`materiales_educativos_entregados`) AS `total_M`,
        `id_persona_receptora`
    FROM
        `promotor_realiza_entrevista_individual`
    GROUP BY `id_persona_receptora`
```

Tabla final de totales

```
    SELECT 
        `i`.`id_persona_receptora` AS `id_persona_receptora`,
        (`i`.`total_C` + `g`.`total_C`) AS `C`,
        (`i`.`total_L` + `g`.`total_L`) AS `L`,
        (`i`.`total_M` + `g`.`total_M`) AS `M`
    FROM
        (`total_grupales` `i`
        LEFT JOIN `total_individuales` `g` ON ((`i`.`id_persona_receptora` = `g`.`id_persona_receptora`)))
```

Comment: Hi post your question in english please, or you can use spanish SO: https://es.stackoverflow.com/

Comment: Sorry. First time asking here

Comment: I will. Thanks for the link

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To avoid the need for the intermediate views, you could aggregate in subqueries and then join:

```
SELECT 
    `i`.`id_persona_receptora` AS `id_persona_receptora`,
    (`i`.`total_C` + `g`.`total_C`) AS `C`,
    (`i`.`total_L` + `g`.`total_L`) AS `L`,
    (`i`.`total_M` + `g`.`total_M`) AS `M`
FROM (
   SELECT 
        SUM(`condones_entregados`) AS `total_C`,
        SUM(`lubricantes_entregados`) AS `total_L`,
        SUM(`materiales_educativos_entregados`) AS `total_M`,
        `id_persona_receptora`
    FROM
        `promotor_realiza_actividad_grupal_con_personas_receptoras`
    GROUP BY `id_persona_receptora`
) `i`
LEFT JOIN (
    SELECT 
        SUM(`condones_entregados`) AS `total_C`,
        SUM(`lubricantes_entregados`) AS `total_L`,
        SUM(`materiales_educativos_entregados`) AS `total_M`,
        `id_persona_receptora`
    FROM
        `promotor_realiza_entrevista_individual`
    GROUP BY `id_persona_receptora`
) `g` ON `i`.`id_persona_receptora` = `g`.`id_persona_receptora`
```

Comment: How can it be that I am able to use the query as such, but when I try to save it in a view I receive the message an error message?

Comment: The number is 1349. Apparently the subqueries are not allow in the FROM sentence of the views. I have found this information a minute ago in another chat